# Strange behavior of Import-Module

Tags: powershell

I have a very strange behavior in PowerShell.

I use the following scripts:

`HelloWorld.psm1`:

```
function Write-HelloWorld {
    "Hello world"
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function Write-HelloWorld
```

`test2.psm1`:

```
Import-Module .\HelloWorld.psm1 -Force
```

`test1.ps1`:

```
Import-Module .\HelloWorld.psm1 -Force

"Is HelloWorld loaded: " + ($null -eq (Get-Module HelloWorld))

Import-Module .\test2.psm1 -Force

"Is HelloWorld loaded: " + ($null -eq (Get-Module HelloWorld))
```

When I run `test1.ps1`, the result is:

```
Is HelloWorld loaded: False
Is HelloWorld loaded: True
```

HelloWorld module gets unloaded when `test2.psm1` is imported. It doesn't seem logic to me... I understand that the scope of HelloWorld module is local in `test2.psm1`, but I would expect that he doesn't unload it at the end, because it was already imported before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `import-module` msdn.

"This parameter [-force] causes a module to be loaded, or reloaded, over top of the current one."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-6

I'm guessing that since HelloWorld is in your test2, it is being forced over the current HelloWorld module, and since its scope is within test2 it shows up that it does exist in the current module.

Comment: Yes you're right, it's working properly without -Force! Thank you ;)